# Unable to restore SQL database, exclusive access could not be obtained (single user mode)

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I am writing a simple database backup and restore routine for an application. I can backup my database without issues, however when I restore is I am unable to gain exclusive access to my database.

I am trying all the combinations of fixes on SO, putting in single user mode, taking it offline then placing it back only with no success. 
I can successfully restore the database within studio manager (express)

This method is the only connection to the SQL server at the time, so I don't understand why I can't perform the restore.

Appreciate the help to point out where the issue may be.

```
internal void RestoreDatabase(string databaseFile)
        {
            //get database details
            var databaseConfiguration = new DatabaseConfiguration().GetDatabaseConfiguration();

            try
            {
                //construct server connection string
                var connection = databaseConfiguration.IsSqlAuthentication
                                     ? new ServerConnection(databaseConfiguration.ServerInstance,
                                                            databaseConfiguration.SqlUsername,
                                                            databaseConfiguration.SqlPassword)
                                     : new ServerConnection(databaseConfiguration.ServerInstance);

                //set database to single user and kick everyone off
                using (
                    var sqlconnection =
                        new SqlConnection(new DatabaseConfiguration().MakeConnectionString(databaseConfiguration)))
                {
                    sqlconnection.Open();
                    using (
                        var sqlcommand = new SqlCommand("ALTER DATABASE " + databaseConfiguration.DatabaseName + " SET Single_User WITH Rollback IMMEDIATE",
                                                        sqlconnection))
                    {                       
                        sqlcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();                        
                    }
                    using (
                        var sqlcommand = new SqlCommand("ALTER DATABASE " + databaseConfiguration.DatabaseName + " SET OFFLINE",
                                                        sqlconnection))
                    {
                        sqlcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    using (
                        var sqlcommand = new SqlCommand("ALTER DATABASE  " + databaseConfiguration.DatabaseName + "  SET ONLINE",
                                                        sqlconnection))
                    {
                        sqlcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    sqlconnection.Close();
                }

                //setup server connection and restore
                var server = new Server(connection);
                var restore = new Restore();
                restore.Database = databaseConfiguration.DatabaseName;
                restore.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;
                restore.Devices.AddDevice(databaseFile, DeviceType.File);
                restore.ReplaceDatabase = true;
                restore.Complete += Restore_Complete;
                restore.SqlRestore(server);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //my bad
                restoreDatabaseServerError(ex.InnerException.Message, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
            finally
            {
                //set database to multi user
                using (
                    var sqlconnection =
                        new SqlConnection(new DatabaseConfiguration().MakeConnectionString(databaseConfiguration)))
                {
                    sqlconnection.Open();
                    using (
                        var sqlcommand = new SqlCommand("ALTER DATABASE " + databaseConfiguration.DatabaseName + " SET Multi_User",
                                                        sqlconnection))
                    {
                        sqlcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        sqlcommand.Dispose();
                    }
                    sqlconnection.Close();
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Sorry if this comment is not helpful but an alternate way to do this (and which would hopefully take care of some of this plumbing stuff for you) is to use SMO. Please see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.backup.sqlbackup%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.restore%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) for the general methods and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162133%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) for a specific example on backup/restore....Sorry again if this comment isn't helpful

Comment: I am using SMO in my example?

Comment: Why is this tagged WPF?

Comment: Because it's a WPF application using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common
 & Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo

Comment: @Damo dude, all the code you posted there has `nothing` to do with WPF. Your question is related to `SQL`, not `WPF`.

Comment: WPF tag removed. I had become accustomed to providing too much information I guess

Comment: Sorry, my mistake in reading the question. Out of curiosity what happens if you don't use SMO but after setting single user (and in the context of your open sqlconnetion you issue a RESTORE DATABASE command manually (well, using SqlCommand) and then you set multi-user?

Comment: On further investigation using SQL Profiler, I may have another object holding my db open... Now to trace it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anybody is connected to your database, SQL Server cannot drop it, so you have to disconnect existing connections, as you have tried. The problem with single_user is, that it still allows a single user to connect. As you yourself cannot be connected to the database when dropping it you have to get out of there. That opens up that slot for someone else to connect and in turn prevent you from dropping it.

There are a few SQL Server processes that are particularly good at connecting to a database in that split second. Replication is one example. (You shouldn't really drop a database that is published anyway, bat that is another story.)

So what can we do about this? The only 100% safe way is to prevent users from connecting to the database. The only practical way is to switch the database offline and then drop it. However, that has the nasty side effect, that SQL Server does not delete the files of that database, so you have to do that manually.

Another option is to just be fast enough. In your example you bring the database back online before you drop it. That is a fairly resource intensive process that gives an "intruder" lots of time to connect.

The solution I have been using with success looks like this:

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDb SET RESTRICTED_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
USE MyDb;
ALTER DATABASE MyDb SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
USE tempdb;
DROP DATABASE MyDb;
```

This first sets the database to restricted user and connects to it. Then, while still connected it sets the database to single user. Afterwards the context is switched to tempdb and the drop is executed immediately thereafter. Important here is, to send these commands as one batch to SQL Server to minimize the time between the `USE tempdb;` and the `DROP`. Setting the database to restricted user in the beginning catches some rare edge cases, so leave it in even though it does not make sense at first glance.

While this still leaves a theoretical gap for someone else to get in, I have never seen it fail.

After the database is dropped you can run your restore as normal.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Your restore needs to take place on the same connection you set the DB server to single user mode.

In summary for the changes below, I moved the end of the using to below your restore code, and moved the close for the SQL connection to after the restore so it uses the same connection. Also removed set offline and online since they aren't needed. Can't test at the moment, so let me know if it works.

```
  //set database to single user and kick everyone off
  using (var sqlconnection = new SqlConnection(new DatabaseConfiguration().MakeConnectionString(databaseConfiguration)))
  {
    sqlconnection.Open();
    using (var sqlcommand = new SqlCommand("ALTER DATABASE " + databaseConfiguration.DatabaseName + " SET Single_User WITH Rollback IMMEDIATE",sqlconnection))
    {
        sqlcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();                        
    }
    //setup server connection and restore
    var server = new Server(sqlconnection);
    var restore = new Restore();
    restore.Database = databaseConfiguration.DatabaseName;
    restore.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;
    restore.Devices.AddDevice(databaseFile, DeviceType.File);
    restore.ReplaceDatabase = true;
    restore.Complete += Restore_Complete;
    restore.SqlRestore(server);
    sqlconnection.Close();
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately 'SqlConnection' and 'ServerConnection' are not compatible. i.e. I can't use the SqlConnection on a Server Action it seems.

Comment: Hi, sorry to stickybeak but there is a ServerConnection [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191639%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) which accepts a SqlConnection object as a parameter to base itself off so perhaps that could help?