# restore sql server from .bak file Exclusive access could not be obtained

Tags: sql, sql-server, backup

I am trying to restore my sql using bak file

I am getting error

Exclusive access could not be obtained because the database is in use

I tried

```
USE [master]
ALTER DATABASE myDB
SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
```

and run the query

```
USE [master] RESTORE DATABASE  myDB
   FROM DISK = 'C:\MyDatabase.bak' WITH  FILE = 1,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
```

I also tried from restore wizard with same result.

Exclusive access could not be obtained because the database is in use.

Comment: Sometimes I drop the db, and quit the SQL Management Studio, and reopen it, then recreate the db using Studio Interface from a full backup disk sql file... be careful!!!

Comment: Make sure *you* don't have MyDB open in some other query window.

Comment: Your solution is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15511895/unable-to-restore-sql-database-exclusive-access-could-not-be-obtained-single-u

Comment: What if I get this error - restoring a database that does NOT exist? I'm even changing the database name to something ridiculous, and making sure the files are also some ridiculous filename that does not exist - and SSMS is STILL telling me that the database (which clearly doesn't even exist) is in use. **EDIT** Apparently unchecking "Backup tail log..." worked. How that got enabled in the first place? I have no idea.

Answer (score 20):

**Method 1**

```
    declare @sql as varchar(20), @spid as int

    select @spid = min(spid)  from master..sysprocesses  where dbid = db_id('<database_name>')  and spid != @@spid    

    while (@spid is not null)

    begin

    print 'Killing process ' + cast(@spid as varchar) + ' ...'

    set @sql = 'kill ' + cast(@spid as varchar)

exec (@sql)

select 

    @spid = min(spid)  

from 

    master..sysprocesses  

where 

    dbid = db_id('<database_name>') 

    and spid != @@spid
 end 

 print 'Process completed...'
```

**Method 2**

```
  alter database database_name
  set offline with rollback immediate
  alter database database_name
  set online
```

go

Comment: Method 2 failed because of "ALTER DATABASE failed because a lock could not be placed on database". I ran sp_who2 to determine the blocking process and then Kill to get rid of it, after which Method 2 worked for me.

Answer (score 19):

Don't need to write any query to solve this problem.
I had the same problem several times and solve it by this method:
when you are restoring database

1. Go to Option tab in Restore database window
2. Check (Overwrite the existing database (WITH REPLACE))
3. Check (Close existing connections to destination database)
4. Then click OK

Restore database is starting...

Comment: This answer got me on the right track. On my Restore options, I also had to uncheck "Tail-Log backup before restore". My situation was: I had a production database backup that I wanted to restore over our dev database to effectively "refresh" our dev database with prod data. I didn't care about keeping anything on our dev db. The ONLY options checked should be #2 and #3 above. Everything else had to be unchecked.

Answer (score 15):

Anyone that has had the issues listed above, and none of the advice works.. Just turn off the Taillog backup under 'options'..

Setting (or leaving) this option on will attempt to take a tail-log of the source database itself (even if your source for the restore is just a file).  So if the source database is in use (which if you are doing a copy of a production DB will normally be the case) then the restore fails.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when I was trying to restore a production backup to a dev server that already had the database there.  I wanted to restore as a copy, which I did by changing the target database name, but the issue was actually with the files.  By default, it was trying to overwrite the files that were already there.  I fixed the issue by checking the "Relocate all files to folder" in the "Files" page of the restore dialog and choosing a new directory so there wouldn't be file collisions.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above solution did not work for me. 
After many trials and errors, I stopped SQL Server Browser and then the restore completed successfully

Answer (score 0):

No solution here worked for me, in the end I reset the SQL Server service itself, after which the restore worked instantly.